# run aapt in c# with arguments

Tags: c#, android, aapt

```
        private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "E:\\aapt.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "aapt d badging app.apk";
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.Start();
        Debug.Write(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().ToString());
        proc.WaitForExit();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I have tried this to start aapt with desired arguments to get desired result, but I get no error and no result.  When I go to drive E and right click while pressing shift and click on  "Open command window here" and then type "aapt d badging app.apk" , I get proper result in cmd.

Comment: proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "E:\\";

Comment: @inquisitive_mind doesn't makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in the code you shared.

- You should just pass the process arguments in StartInfo.Arguments 
  So in your case, it should be

  proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "d badging app.apk";
- By setting RedirectStandardOutput to true, the output of the process is suppressed from displaying on the console. So, either you use set RedirectStandardOutput to false and print using Debug.Write. Or, use Console.Writeline to print proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()